# Текст на Image

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения, текст

Только начал писать на WPF. По ходу появила такая проблема: необходимо на компонент Image выводить текст, который по ходу программы будет меняться. Как можно это реализовать? В гугле нашел только какие варианты с TextBlock в xaml-файле.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень правильные варианты вы нашли в гугле.

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="..."/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding YourText}"/>
</Grid>
```

Или вы собирались на лету патчить картинку?

Comment: У меня в программе массив Imageй, источник картинки я указываю в C# коде

 ImageSourceConverter imgs = new ImageSourceConverter();
this.Card.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, imgs.ConvertFromString("CardOpen.png"));

можно примерно таким же образом и текст туда запихнуть?
Я даже до определенного момента и не знаю, что за текст там будет находиться, но в каждом Image разный.

Comment: Вы пишете как на WinForms. Освойте MVVM и делайте через Binding. Вручную устанавливать атрибуты элементов -- 19 век.

Comment: я до этого писал только на WinForms, вот перехожу на WPF, но пока технология эта не весьма понятна

Comment: Почитайте про Binding, DependencyProperty и ViewModel, сразу станет легче писать на WPF, и сразу станет понятно, чем это круче WinForms. Честно. Если вам приходится манипулировать контролами в коде, скорее всего, вы делаете что-то неправильно. Всё (почти всё) должно быть в XAML.